# Rerunning the Django Project

Tags: mysql, django

Intitally when i setup i didn't have any error when i typed python manage.py runserver. However when i installed mysql and changed admins and databases in my settings.py, i can't seem to run the server again.

Setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

When i run python manage.py run server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Comment: This happened only when you changed the database entry? I would say that your database entry is incomplete, but that wouldn't explain your error

Comment: after i changed my admin details as well.. download the mysql as well..

Comment: This shows signs of environment paths changing, if you claim it worked before. So if you change this back to sqlite3, it will work again?

Comment: There you go. Its obviously not related to changing your admin details or the database. Check that you having changed shells, or forgot to set an env or something

Comment: name , mysql user are mandatory fields i think........

Comment: thanks... i forgot to set an env... but my question is why does it affect if it doesn't have an env? i dun understand....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to make sure to active your `env` as you noticed.  As you can see the `django` package ONLY exists in your env.  If you are not using it then you can not access any part of the django package (`django.core.management`)  THere are many man tutorials explaining how virtualenv functions.

http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/10/22/working-virtualenv/

http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/